# how can I start my express server with nodemon with commands in package.json?

Tags: node.js

I can start my server with nodemon src/server.ts but I want it start via package.json with command like npm start.

How can I do it ?

I have seen a tutorial but it not works it shows me a error the command is wrong:

```
"start:nodemon": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js",
```

from this site
[enter link description here](https://dev.to/admirnisic/create-new-node-js-application-with-express-typescript-nodemon-and-eslint-f2l)

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "express_inngest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node ./src/server.ts",
    "start:nodemon": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js",
    "start:prod": "npm run build && node ./dist/src/server.js",
    "build": "npx tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.9",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

nodemon json

```
{
  "ignore": [".git", "node_modules", "dist"],
  "watch": ["./src"], 
  "exec": "npm start", 
  "ext": "ts" 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much to explain, here is a config for I use your directory structure.

```
//package.json

"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon",
    "start:raw": "ts-node ./src/server.ts",
    "start:prod": "npm run build && node ./dist/src/server.js",
    "build": "npx tsc"
  },
```

```
// nodemon.json
{
  "ignore": [".git", "node_modules", "dist"],
  "watch": ["./src"],
  "exec": "ts-node ./src/server.ts",
  "ext": "ts"
}
```

so, you can update your config like this